# Cannot read property '_pending' of null when using v-html and <transition>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I’ve been fighting this bug for several hours and managed to narrow it down to a very simple script. I managed to reproduce the error in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hdodov/cj7cwrfy/).

I want to display a price based on a given currency. If the currency is `USD`, simply display the price. If it’s something else, display a converted price (in this case, to `EUR`) with the option to click on it and see the original price.

As you can see in the fiddle, if you change the initial `USD` in the input to lets say, `US`, the condition is no longer met and the converted price is shown. If you click on the price, you can see the original price.

However, if you type `D` back so that the currency is `USD` again, you get the error:

```
vue.js:1743 TypeError: Cannot read property '_pending' of null
    at performLeave (VM208 vue.js:7827)
    at leave (VM208 vue.js:7817)
    at Array.remove$$1 (VM208 vue.js:7910)
    at removeAndInvokeRemoveHook (VM208 vue.js:5771)
    at removeAndInvokeRemoveHook (VM208 vue.js:5768)
    at removeVnodes (VM208 vue.js:5745)
    at patchVnode (VM208 vue.js:5928)
    at updateChildren (VM208 vue.js:5809)
    at patchVnode (VM208 vue.js:5923)
    at Vue.patch [as __patch__] (VM208 vue.js:6083)
```

Upon inspecting the Vue source code, it appears that the internal `performLeave()` method tries to access `_pending` of `el.parentNode`. Since that method is used for transitioning and the only transitioning element is the `<span>` with `key="a"`, I guess that `el` is that element and the needed parent node is the `<span>` with `v-if="converted"`.

Probably this happens because I have `v-html` in the `v-else` of the problematic parent. The nested child tries to transition, but the HTML of the parent is changed, thus the child no longer has a parent?

See the error for yourself in either the fiddle or this snippet:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function () {
        return {
            original: '$500',
            currency: 'USD',
            show: true
        };
    },
    computed: {
        converted: function () {
            return (this.currency !== 'USD') ? '€423' : null;
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <input v-model="currency">
    
    <span v-if="converted" @click="show = !show">
        <transition name="fade">
            <span v-if="show" key="a" v-html="converted"></span>
            <span v-else key="b" v-html="original"></span>
        </transition>
    </span>
    <span v-else v-html="original"></span>
</div>
```

### Questions

1. Why is this error occurring? What happens?
2. How do I fix it?

Comment: Just change `return (this.currency !== 'USD') ? '€423' : null;` to `return (this.currency !== 'USD') ? '€423' : this.original;`

Comment: That completely changes the logic and I can toggle between the original price and... the original price again. Because your edit turns the converted price into the original one.

Comment: I see, I guess I should have said: _and remove_ `<span v-if="converted"...</span>`. Would be much simpler and you could just toggle a css class on that single `span` for transitions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with Vue. Here's the [ticket for the bug on Vue's repo on GitHub](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8199).

It appears that the specific combination of having the `v-if` on the first span, *and* the `@click="show = !show"` event listener, *and* the `<transition>` tag, *and* rendering the content of the last `<span>` with `v-html` instead of string interpolation is causing some wires to get crossed and causing Vue to error out. Change any of those conditions, and the code works.

One easy workaround would be to use `v-show="converted"` and `v-show="!converted"` for the two outer spans instead of the `v-if` and `v-else` directives.

The suggested workaround from the Vue team is to add a unique `key` attribute to the outer span elements like so:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function () {
        return {
            original: '$500',
            currency: 'USD',
            show: true
        };
    },
    computed: {
        converted: function () {
            return (this.currency !== 'USD') ? '€423' : null;
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <input v-model="currency">
    
    <span v-if="converted" key="a" @click="show = !show">
        <transition name="fade">
            <span v-if="show" key="a" v-html="converted"></span>
            <span v-else key="b" v-html="original"></span>
        </transition>
    </span>
    <span v-else key="b" v-html="original"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: While debugging, I noticed that you can also make it work by changing the last span to `<span v-else>{{ original }}</span>`, I.E. using string interpolation instead of `v-html`. If `v-if` is the problem, how does _that_ work?

Comment: Hmm, good point. Yeah, as far as I know, the same span should be getting reused by Vue in that v-if / v-else pair, so I'm not sure why the `parentNode` is `null`. My guess is that it's a bug with Vue not handling the element correctly because of the v-html directory. You could maybe submit a ticket on their GitHub. Using v-show, or your suggestion of not using the v-html directive are both good workarounds. No time now, but I'll come back and update my answer soon.

Comment: @HristiyanDodov updated based on Vue team's response.